# gsub() not recognizing and replacing certain accented characters

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, data-cleaning

I have a `df` with various names, many of which contain accented/non-English characters. I used `gsub`'s for each of the characters I wanted to replace, and that worked for many of them; however, for several of the characters, it did not replace them at all.

An example of the non-working `gsub`: `gsub("č","c",df,fixed=TRUE)`

Here are the characters that were not replaced: `ł ř ń š ž Ľ ţ ę č ć`

My wish is to replace them with their English "look-alike" equivalent: `l r n s z L t e c c`

In addition to the `gsub` attempts, I have also tried using `chartr("łřńšžĽţęčć","lrnszLtecc",df$Name)`. Like the `gsub` attempts, this ended in failure as well.

```
df<-data.frame(Name=c("Stipe Miočić","Duško Todorović","Michał Oleksiejczuk","Jiři Prochazka","Bartosz Fabiński","Damir Hadžović","Ľudovit Klein","Diana Belbiţă","Joanna Jędrzejczyk" ))
```

Above is a `df` with several of the names that are giving me trouble, the problem is, when you run this and view the resulting `df` it removes all of the characters that are giving me problems and shows English versions of those characters. However, it does not do this in my main `df` I'm working on with directly scraped data.

Any insight into this problem and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my case `gsub("č","c", "časaer", fixed=TRUE)` is working, as well as the other characters. May this depend on the OS? I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `stringi::stri_trans_general`:

```r
library(stringi)
df<-data.frame(Name=c("Stipe Miočić","Duško Todorović","Michał Oleksiejczuk","Jiři Prochazka","Bartosz Fabiński","Damir Hadžović","Ľudovit Klein","Diana Belbiţă","Joanna Jędrzejczyk" ))
stri_trans_general(df$Name, "Latin-ASCII")
```

**Results**:

```
[1] "Stipe Miocic"        "Dusko Todorovic"     "Michal Oleksiejczuk"
[4] "Jiri Prochazka"      "Bartosz Fabinski"    "Damir Hadzovic"     
[7] "Ludovit Klein"       "Diana Belbita"       "Joanna Jedrzejczyk"
```

See [R proof](https://tio.run/##NY/BSgMxEIbv@xRD8LALrU@gB6uIrVaFei/TTbadJk1kkhW6RxU8@QA9is@hp81zbRPEyzB8M/MNPw@DoRUj70sfmOyaqkI2Z2OJAU8bxp0q71M5r0uxCPSsYE6u/6T@Q4zEVRu/tIMnJx27lz82p3qD8RUejNKe1LbuWp3wjOKB4JFdmnYaE5kgB@c7uMYVxXevKQtxRww3KOPvv6//aWXqA9waRTbvEFqEiTLp7Lt/y26HNqFZf5Dc5Y97LaCqipxnGRitX66VVYymlM1JTjMCcYeB7PhicTmdiqoYhiM).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stringi::replace_all_fixed`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_all_fixed(df$Name,
                       c("ł","ř","ń","š","ž","Ľ","ţ","ę","č","ć"),
                       c("l","r","n","s","z","L","t","e","c","c"),
                       vectorize_all = FALSE)
[1] "Stipe Miocic"        "Dusko Todorovic"     "Michal Oleksiejczuk" "Jiri Prochazka"      "Bartosz Fabinski"   
[6] "Damir Hadzovic"      "Ludovit Klein"       "Diana Belbită"       "Joanna Jedrzejczyk"
```